# Vectorization with varying colindices

Tags: r, matrix

I would like to perform some operations on a simple matrix, let's say:

```
aaa <- matrix(runif(200), ncol=5)
aaa
```

What I'd like to do: add a number - for example 100 - to certain values of the matrix at fixed rows (i.e. there should be a fixed distance), but varying (i.e. there should be no pattern here) columns.

For example see the desired output after some modifications:

```
aaa[1:5, c(3,5)] <- aaa[1:5, c(3,5)] + 100
aaa[11:15, c(1,2)] <- aaa[11:15, c(1,2)] + 100
aaa[21:25, c(4,5)] <- aaa[21:25, c(4,5)] + 100
aaa[31:35, c(1,5)] <- aaa[31:35, c(1,5)] + 100
aaa
```

I also have a matrix of the columns which are to be modified:

```
bbb <- matrix(cbind(c(3,5),c(1,2),c(4,5),c(1,5)), ncol = 4)
```

and the following vector of row indices

```
ccc <- c(1:5, 11:15, 21:25, 31:35)
```

This can be solved by using a loop, but can it also be solved by vectorization? From my understanding it is not possible because the columns are varying. Or am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it can be done using code of the form:

```
Mat[ cbind( rows, cols) ] <- vals
```

I don't think your expectations re: indexing are correct. You could do:

```
Idx <- cbind( rep( 1:5, 2), rep( c(2,5), 5) )
aaa[Idx]<-aaa[Idx]+100
```

You can construct new vectors from 'bbb' and 'ccc' with:

```
cbind( ccc, # will get recycled
  c( apply(bbb,2, rep, each=5) ) )
```

And then :

```
Idx <- cbind( ccc, c( apply(bbb, 2, rep, each=5) ) )

aaa[ Idx] <- aaa[Idx]+100
```

Comment: Hello 42-, could you elaborate a bit with regard to my example? I cannot simply cbind(rows,cols) because of incorrect dimensions.

Comment: It depends on your intent with the use of c(2,5). I'm guessing you meant to use rep(2,5)?

Comment: No, e. g. by c(2, 5) I meant to address the cols with index 2 and 5. These column indices vary on purpose between iterations.

Comment: Then I can't figure out what you intend the indexing to do when you pair that with 1:5 for the rows.

Comment: Hmm why not? In the above example I wrote `aaa[1:5, c(3,5)] <- aaa[1:5, c(3,5)] + 100` etc., this is what I try to achive. As you can see the row indices always increase by 10 per command (or iteration in a loop) and the colindices vary arbitrarily. 3 and 5 is were just randomly used for illustration in this MWE. Why does a pairing of 1:5 (rows) with 3, 5 (columns) not make sense to you? Its like [1,3],[2,3]...[5,3] and [1,5][2,5]...[5,5]. Maybe there is a better way to write this/handle this issue?

Comment: It doesn't make sense to me because that's not how indexing works in R. There is recycling if the two vectors have lengths that are multiples. You can achieve it but it takes extra work.

Comment: Ok I thought indexing the following way is ok: `Mat[c(row1, row2,...) , c(col1, col2,...)]`, or at least I often used it like that

Comment: yes I know the recycling rule, but I don't understand how this is an issue in indexing a matrix. If I run the above lines of code ('desired output'), it does not throw an error

Comment: So am I right assuming that Vectorization is not possible in this case?

Comment: Disagree. I would consider building vectors with rep and cbind-ing to be vectorization.

Comment: thanks for the example, but your output is different from mine (see 'desired output'). But I think I understand what you intend: 1 row index for every colindex. /e: I believe I also got why you need this form of indexing in my case. Thanks. If you fix your code to produce the correct output I will accept your answer.

Comment: Check it in a minute.